# Unable connect to MySQL from C# but possible from other apps

Tags: c#, python, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I wanted to change MySQL server in my C# app. The app is run in my company and both - old and new MySQL servers are only accessible from the intranet. The problem is **I can connect** from HeidiSQL software and from python code **but not from C#...**

I have tried all possible solutions what I found, for ex. disabling firewall, using different packages from NuGet, modifying connection string, I created new console project only to paste various MySQL connection code - always with same error

```
Message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Source: MySql.Data
Number: 1042
```

I', using .net Framework 4.5.2 (4.6.1 in my test project) and MySQL Server is '5.6.44-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)'

---

One of C# connection code example that I have tested that is NOT working

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
public static MySqlConnection DB_connection;

DB_connection = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=MyIP;Database=myDB;Uid=my_user;Pwd=pass;");
try
{
    DB_connection.Open();
    isConn = true;
}
catch (...)
```

Working python code run from the same PC

```
import pymysql
import pprint

connection = pymysql.connect(host='MyIP',
                             user='my_user',
                             password='pass',
                             db='myDB')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "select * from table;"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # connection.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        pprint.pprint(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: `MyIP` is not a valid IP address or a hostname change it to something else like `'127.0.0.1'` or `'localhost'`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi obviously that's an example since posting hostname/ip address publicly isn't a good idea

Comment: like @Rahul said, MyIP is in 178.0.(..) form

Comment: What happens when you ping the ip from cmd ?

Comment: Pings are disabled but telnet is fine (from CMD) but from VStuido is not

Comment: Did you disable the firewall on your computer or on the remote ? You might need to disable it on your computer because the firewall might block the C# program from accessing the Internet

Comment: I did disable it on my PC, I don't have access to remote (I had to the previous one, but current is more official)

Comment: Is python code and c# code running on the same machine?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, on the same machine and connection, I have just checked to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong with your posted connection string but in case your's is a replicated scenario (I mean DB replication exists) then you will have to specify the replicated server IP/hostname as well like

```
Server=serverAddress1, serverAddress2, serverAddress3;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: But OP says it's working on Python so why not work on C# ?

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi have no idea about Python .. may be python connector can pick up the hot host anyway

Comment: previous server was tunneled by SSH so it's kinda different thing. This code was working before so now I started thinking maybe some firewall on the intranet it's blocking it or server itself... I'm so confused by this problem...

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Yes, I have just checked. HeidiSQL is also working

Comment: Maybe you are using an old or deprecated version of `mysql-connector`. Try using the latest version and see if it works.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I had download new version from nuGet few times and also I had tried package from different vendors/developers. Same result :(

Comment: @Rasiel Can you post the full source code of the C# application ? It might be something in the code which is causing the connection to fail.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi well it's almost 20k lines but I have made new console app project with only connection string and its also not working. I have tried various examples of connection code from the google. Now I'm not sure it is C# issue... it is working with different server...